# Make different couples in Netlogo in each iteration

Tags: netlogo

I have 100 agents of two types, I call them x and y, which I name randomly by a flyer in each tick. I want to make each agent 'x' interact with an agent 'y' on each tick. My question is, How can I make them interact a number 'n' of times in each tick?

I do not know how to define 'n' interactions in each tick

```
ask x [                                        
      let target y                                
      face target                                        
      fd 5
      interaction
]
```

Comment: use the repeat keyword